# Переадрессация при авторизации

Tags: битрикс

Есть дефолтная форма авторизации:

```
<form name="form_auth" method="post" target="_top" action="<?=$arResult["AUTH_URL"]?>">
<input type="hidden" name="AUTH_FORM" value="Y" />
<input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="AUTH" />
<?if (strlen($arResult["BACKURL"]) > 0):?>
<input type="hidden" name="backurl" value="<?=$arResult["BACKURL"]?>" />
<?endif?>
<?foreach ($arResult["POST"] as $key => $value):?>
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$key?>" value="<?=$value?>" />
<?endforeach?>                                
<label>Email/логин<span>*</span></label>
<input name="USER_LOGIN" maxlength="255" value="<?=$arResult["LAST_LOGIN"]?>" class="simple-field" type="text" placeholder="Введите Email/логин (обязательно)" required />
<label>Пароль<span>*</span></label>
<input name="USER_PASSWORD" class="simple-field" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" required />
<div class="button style-10">Войти<input type="submit" name="Login" value="" /></div>
</form>
```

При успешной авторизации, как я понял, должна происходить переадресация на страницу с которой производилась авторизация, но почему то этого не происходит, а открывается страница успешной авторизации `/auth/?login=yes`
то есть BACKURL всегда равен `/auth/`

Куда копать, смотрел похожие темы, но ответа так и не нашел...

И сразу второй вопрос стоит ли менять этот шаблон или же стоит на его основе сделать свой?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас стоит на странице компонент `bitrix:system.auth.form` то делаем следующее,
заходим в в папку `/bitrix/components/bitrix/system.auth.form/` открываем файл 
`component.php` находим там параметр `$arResult['AUTH_URL']` и видим правило если у нас заполнена константа `defined("AUTH_404")` то `BACKURL URL` будет браться от туда, если нет то на текущею страницу. 
Константа может быть установлена до пролога в документации битрикс это есть https://yadi.sk/i/HEOa4SKIC2Govw
Этот шаблон править нельзя нужно скопировать его в свой шаблон сайта и там править как нужно вам.

Comment: компонент используется bitrix/templates/toysales_pink/components/bitrix/system.auth.form/top/template.php но сама страница авторизации находится по адресу bitrix/templates/.default/components/bitrix/system.auth.authorize/.default/template.php причем ни там ни там нет файла component.php

Comment: Так вам component.php не нужен это компонент его трогать не нужно, они лежать в /bitrix/components/bitrix/system.auth.form/ по этому вы их не найдете у себя в шаблоне, вам нужно скопировать шаблон компонента к себе и изменять как вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим вы сейчас находитесь на странице /catalog/ и в шапке сайта есть ссылка "Войти"
При нажатии на ссылку вы попадаете на страницу с формой авторизации. После авторизации необходимо попасть обратно в /catalog/. Если это так, надо просто для ссылки "Войти" добавить GET параметр `backurl=%2Fcatalog%2F`